# Custom Post type templates not working in wp

Tags: wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I have some categories like about-us, services etc and want to show different templates for these categories. I have read from wp site to make files name like category-slug.php where slug may be about-us or services. I made these files but they didn't worked for me. Instead of these templates the index file displays the posts. I want to display posts from these categories in custom files.

Can any one tell me how to do this?

Comment: You are correct, it should work like you described. Just check again you have named and placed the files correctly in your theme folder, the categories exist and have posts assigned to them...

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<?php /*
Template Name: ListPostsInCategoryThatHasSameNameAsPage
*/ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
<div id="main">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>

    <?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<p><?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>

</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Dont use query_posts, really. Use WP_Query instead